# Issue with custom inflections in Ruby on Rails 3.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called **produccion_alternativa**.
I added a new inflection rule in config/initializers/inflections.rb, like this:

```
inflect.irregular('produccion_alternativa', 'producciones_alternativas')
```

I have other model called **productor** that has a relation with **produccion_alternativa**:

```
class Productor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :producciones_alternativas


class ProduccionAlternativa < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :productor
```

When I try to get all the **producciones_alternativas** for a **productor**, I get this error:

```
irb(main):010:0> Productor.first.producciones_alternativas
NameError: uninitialized constant Productor::ProduccionesAlternativa
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I see several others having the same problem. Couldn't find an answer why this happens. So in the meantime you could just try this:

```
has_many :producciones_alternativas, :class_name => "ProduccionAlternativa"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution too. I added another rule on inflection.rb:

```
inflect.irregular('ProduccionAlternativa', 'ProduccionesAlternativas')
inflect.irregular('produccion_alternativa', 'producciones_alternativas')
```

At least, now it's working as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Your Fail is that you pluralized both words in `has_many` association. You used:

```
has_many :producciones_alternativas
```

but based on the class name `ProduccionAlternativa` the plural is `produccion_alternativas` because only the last word is pluralized! So this should work:

```
has_many :produccion_alternativas
```

To check the Plural of a word type `"your_word".pluralize` in the rails console!