# Rails 3: Routing and pluralization issue for has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, plural

I created a scaffold for Etho, where I am attempting to have a User get 1 single "ethos" to edit. Ethos was working but on the User model it was only working with has_many :ethos

The user should only get 1 so I can create better associations. But now when I change in the model, it creates quite the spider effect that I can't track down.

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_one  :ethos #used to be has_many :ethos
```

On all the pages now I get uninitialized constant User::Ethos on EthosController#edit

Please help, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_one  :etho
```

`has_one` should be singular: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association

Comment: Right. But the second part describes what I can't figure out. has_one :etho gives undefined method `ethos' for #<User:0x000001032c4b70> on EthosController#edit

Comment: In your controller you need to change the `User.ethos` to `User.etho`. It must be singular as well. If it doesn't solve the problem please include the code for your controller.

Comment: Here is the public gist. It's working to where a user can now create an etho, but they should only have 1* and once it's created they should only be able to edit that 1* etho https://gist.github.com/3078792

Comment: as you have a `has_one` relationship, it won't allow you to create more than one `etho` for each `user`. What problem are you facing now? I sugest you to open a new question if you have a different problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can continue to use the *ethos* pluralized name by explicitly specifying the `class_name` on the `has_one` association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_one  :ethos, class_name: 'Ethos'
```

This answer provides additional details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6604247/37966