# How to properly define irregular words in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634043/issue-with-custom-inflections-in-ruby-on-rails-3-0-3).

What is the proper thing to do when you want Rails and all its helpers to work correctly with words like `CarsForRent` given that you follow conventions for database and file namings?

`inflect.irregular 'car for rent', 'cars for rent'` doesn't seem to be enough.

For example, when I generate a model with name `CarForRent` Rails creates a file named `car_for_rents`. Is it not smart enough to recognize that `CarForRent` is like `car for rent`?
Do I have to explicitly define `inflect.irregular 'car_for_rent', 'cars_for_rent'` or is there a better way?

Comment: Please give us a more explit desctription of what you want to do!

Answer (score 0):

as i recollect rails takes an uppercase and realises that there should be a break in the word (CamelCase) and replaces it with an underscore, I am not sure if you can override this with configuration, my suggestion would be to use a table called "rental" or something along those lines.

Hope this helps?